# How do I tackle the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_\mathbb Re^{-(x-y)^2/4kt}f(y)\,dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I ran into this derivative while working on PDEs

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_\mathbb Re^{-(x-y)^2/4kt}f(y)\,dy$$

Embarrassingly, I can't seem to make progress here. I can't think of a function $g$ such that I can have a tractable application of the chain rule $(\partial I)(\partial t)=(\partial I/\partial g)(\partial g/\partial t)$ since $\partial I/\partial g$ seems nonobvious with the integral over the real line.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: It seems that you can interchange the integration operation and the time derivative. Then you can take the derivative of the integrand (for non-zero $t$).